# ANTLR4 Parser, Visitor not created

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4, eclipse-kepler

I'm new to ANTLR and trying to write grammar in ANTLR4 without any prior brush with the previous version. I'm following the book '*The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference*'. I use Eclipse and installed ANTLR4 IDE as given in [here](https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide). I wrote the following grammar in Expr.g4:

```
grammar Expr;

import Common;

options{
language = Java;
}
prog: stat+;

stat: expr NEWLINE
    | ID '=' expr NEWLINE
    | NEWLINE;

expr: expr ('/'|'*') expr
    | expr ('+'|'-') expr
    | INT
    | ID
    | '('expr')';
```

The Common.g4 contains the following:

```
lexer grammar Common;

ID: [A-Za-z]+;
INT: [0-9]+;
NEWLINE: '\r'?'\n';
WS: [\t]+ -> skip;
```

The lexer.java was created but not parser.java and visitor.java and other base file. Please help me fix the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough information. Are you sure the parser and visitor are supposed to be generated? Did you look in the correct directories? Perhaps you should review the documentation and/or issue tracker once more.

Comment: @blackcompe Yes, I have used other grammar and checked. When I saved the file all the files were created automatically. But not in the above case.

Comment: I have same problem, have you found solution?

Answer (score 8):

In fact I had the same problem once, I used to integrate two G4 files within the same project the first one generated Visitor but the second didn't.

Then I realized that each G4 file has its own configuration for code generation that you can change by:

1. Right click on the G4 file then `Run As`
2. Choose `External tool configuration`
3. Change the **no-visitor** to **visitor**, you can do the same for
   listener.

Now the `Visitor` file is generated.

Comment: This did the trick for me!  I was getting no visitor files.  I am using just one G4 file, but knowing that each G4 file has its own tool configuration was the key...

Answer (score 6):

For Maven it was not clear from the documentation how to set the `visitor` property. You have to do it in the  element.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${antlr.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <visitor>true</visitor>
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should generate your grammars during the build process. Starting with ANTLR 4.2 (which is currently available through the Sonatype snapshot Maven repository as 4.2-SNAPSHOT), the Maven plugin supports Eclipse m2e. The documentation for the Maven plugin is available here:

http://www.antlr.org/api/maven-plugin/master/index.html

I would not trust any build which uses ANTLR grammars and does not automate the code generation steps into the build itself, and ***highly recommend*** you avoid using manual code generation steps or code generation as part of an IDE extension *ever*.

Answer (score 2):

Check your JRE version (command line [windows]: java -version).

I was having the same problem with this [example](https://github.com/stfairy/learn-antlr4/blob/master/tpantlr2-code/tour/Expr.g4).
because the **JRE 8**.

So, if you have JRE8, Posible solutions are:

- adding **-version:1.7** in eclipse.ini ;  or
- in the "Run As/External Tools Configurations...", adding **-version:1.7** in Arguments;  or
- selecting **JRE 1.7** in Windows/Java/Installed JREs

To generate XXXVisitor, in "Run As/External Tools Configurations..." change **-no-visitor** argument by **-visitor**.

- Works for -version:1.6, too.

Comment: When you are using command line to generate the java class use `-visitor`  as arg as mentioned above to generate the visitor class.

Answer (score 1):

Preference -> ANTLR4 -> Tool -> Options -> Generate parse tree visitor